# Verifying GeoIP databases come from GeoIP

Tags: automation, code-signing, geoip

I'm hoping to automate the downloading and installation of the free GeoIP databases and I want to know if there is any additional verification options avaliable given that MD5 is becoming more susceptible to pre-image attacks.

Additionaly the MD5 Sums are stored on the same server meaning any attacker breaking into that server will be able to upload potentially malicious database and have it be served without any client being the wiser.

GPG is a common verification tool, and it would be trivial to set up for most Linux users given their package managers already perform this sort of verification.

Comment: What is the risk of someone hack into GeoIP server and change the CSV database to wrong information? Why should one doing that?

Comment: Firstly, one should not ignore security because "it's only a text file", or "my service isn't important".

Secondly, There are not only CSV files; there are also BIN files(in what ever format they are). And bugs occur in code all the time, what if an attacker exploited a vuln in your parsing code.

Thirdly, an attacker could simply make the file large locking up resources & file space.

Finally, Automation of downloading GeoIP databases means the time between a hack occurring and it ending up on a server is reduced; and the time to detect and remedy before impact is reduced as well.

Answer (score 0):

maxmind.com supports TLS SSL HTTPS on its download links (just add the 's' yourself), so be sure to keep your certificates accurate and libraries up to date and you should be as secure as is possible.

Even assuming their webserver gets hijacked, there's really no point in fretting about MD5 vs SHA vs GPG at that point as you would have no reasonable assurances or concept of the width and breadth of the attack.  It might as well be an inside job intentionally perpetrated by the company themselves.  maxmind makes no fitness guarantees against human or automated error, anyway, so take it under advisement.

For a free service (free database, free bandwidth, huge weekly updates) you can't exactly go begging for air-gapped fort knox rate security.  TLS is already better than you'll need.

You are welcome to perform your own sanity-checking of a newly downloaded database against the previously downloaded database, to make sure any changes or corrections are nominally insignificant.  Better still, you can use their GeoIP Update program or direct-download patches.  This way, you are only downloading nominally insignificant updates to begin with, and can inspect them yourself before merging them into the database.  And you'll be saving bandwidth for everyone.